# Using AWK in Bash Script and append two files where the second file is in another folder

Tags: bash, awk

I have two files:

file1.txt:

```
samplefolder_appendtext.txt [ 

1.23 34.2 12.4 5.34 56.3

12.2 24.1 1.42 21.4 1.24

42.1 12.4 12.4 56.5 2.53

1.24 4.64 2.23 1.42 1.42

1.45 12.4 45.2 12.4 35.2 ]
```

appendtext.txt:

```
1.12 34.1 12.4 53.1

12.3 12.4 45.2 23.2

12.4 34.1 34.5 56.3

12.2 34.2 12.3 34.2 

12.4 34.2 12.4 12.1
```

the second file is in "samplefolder" folder

how can I get the output file as following using AWK

```
samplefolder_appendtext.txt [

1.23 34.2 12.4 5.34 56.3 1.12 34.1 12.4 53.1

12.2 24.1 1.42 21.4 1.24 12.3 12.4 45.2 23.2

42.1 12.4 12.4 56.5 2.53 12.4 34.1 34.5 56.3

1.24 4.64 2.23 1.42 1.42 12.2 34.2 12.3 34.2 

1.45 12.4 45.2 12.4 35.2 12.4 34.2 12.4 12.1 ]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow, please wrap your samples in CODE TAGS.

Comment: Unix and its commands don't care which folder a file is in. If you are in `/your/dir` and you want to access `/your/dir/subdir/file` you can refer to it as `subdir/file` or `/your/dir/subdir/file` or `../dir/subdir/file` or any other relative path.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us what you tried.

Answer (score 2):

A simple `paste` command could help here.

```
paste file1.txt  appendtext.txt
```

Comment: But that does not give the desired output

Comment: @NarsimhaKethiri, please spend sometime to edit your output in code tags in your post, without code tags whatever it looked I given solution as per it. you could see`{}` button in your post while editing it.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13: +1, I agree that paste is more than enough for this task.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your 2 input files let's say `file1` and `file2` and as it as been answered by **RavinderSingh13** a `paste` command will do the trick as shown hereunder:

```
$ cat file1 
samplefolder_appendtext.txt [ 

1.23 34.2 12.4 5.34 56.3

12.2 24.1 1.42 21.4 1.24

42.1 12.4 12.4 56.5 2.53

1.24 4.64 2.23 1.42 1.42

1.45 12.4 45.2 12.4 35.2 ]

$ cat file2
1.12 34.1 12.4 53.1

12.3 12.4 45.2 23.2

12.4 34.1 34.5 56.3

12.2 34.2 12.3 34.2 

12.4 34.2 12.4 12.1

$ (head -2 file1; paste -d' ' <(sed '1,2d;s/ ]//g' file1) file2) | sed '$s/$/ ]/'
samplefolder_appendtext.txt [ 

1.23 34.2 12.4 5.34 56.3 1.12 34.1 12.4 53.1

12.2 24.1 1.42 21.4 1.24 12.3 12.4 45.2 23.2

42.1 12.4 12.4 56.5 2.53 12.4 34.1 34.5 56.3

1.24 4.64 2.23 1.42 1.42 12.2 34.2 12.3 34.2 

1.45 12.4 45.2 12.4 35.2 12.4 34.2 12.4 12.1 ]
```

1. `sed '1,2d;s/ ]//g' file1` is used to remove the first 2 lines and the last `]` at the end of file1
2. `paste -d' ' <(sed '1,2d;s/ ]//g' file1) file2` is used to redirect the stdout of sed as if it was a file and pass it with file2 to `paste` command where you set the delimiters as space.
3. `(head -2 file1;...) | sed '$s/$/ ]/'` is used to format back the output file to respect your output format: adding the 2 first line of file1 and adding at the end of the output `]`.